# How to install Android OS and Android Apps on PC?

Tags: android

How to install Android OS and Android Apps on PC ? If possible , android 4.0.3 .

Comment: y is this off topic?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just want to install apps, you can use [Bluestacks](http://bluestacks.com/) or [Youwave](http://youwave.com/)

Answer (score 2):

There is [Android-x86](http://www.android-x86.org/), which you can install as a full operating system on your computer, and acts as the Android OS, complete with apps and all. There are a lot of bugs, and it may not even work on your hardware.

[image]

Android provides an [emulator](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/emulator.html) that you can use, although I'm not sure how well you can load apps onto it, it's mostly for development. There's a lot of documentation on the same page I linked for the emulator.

Comment: Also, while Ax86 works for the most part, things like wireless and ethernet don't. The OP May be better searching for an android emulator.

Comment: @tombull89 Good point - Added on a bit